# Create Custom Post Type as page

Tags: custom-post-types, urls

I need to save URL's from old site, in options-permalink in admin wordpress i use

```
/blog/%category%/%postname%.html
```

I do it for blog posts. **But i don't need to get it for CPT**

I have created CPT

```
function uslugi_init() {
    $args = array(
      'label' => 'Услуги',
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'page',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'uslugi-i-czenyi'),
        'query_var' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-video-alt',
        'supports' => array(
            'title',
            'editor',
            'excerpt',
            'trackbacks',
            'custom-fields',
            'comments',
            'revisions',
            'thumbnail',
            'author',
            'page-attributes',)
        );
    register_post_type( 'uslugi', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'uslugi_init' );
```

BUT i have a big problem - my CPT url is

`site.com/blog/uslugi-i-czenyi/test`

but i need

`site.com/uslugi-i-czenyi/test`

Also i need to get templates from pages...

Is it fixable?

**How to separate CPT url from blog permalink?**

Help me, please!

Answer (score 1):

You can make a custom template for a custom post type. Generally I use the single.php file and duplicate it. Then I rename it to single-{custom-post-type}.php as per [Post Type Templates](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Type_Templates). In your case the template file should look like this single-uslugi.php.

As far as saving the old URLs and fixing things I don't quite understand what you are looking for. More information about the problem is needed before I can contribute to a solution.

Comment: I try to explain: i need CPT url's separated from blog permalink as i enter in admin panel.

Comment: Heres a suggested fix [Remove Blog Prefix](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-add-blog-prefix-for-custom-post-types-in-permalinks)

Answer (score 1):

Should work

```
'with_front' => false,
```

'**with_front**' => bool Should the permalink structure be prepended with the front base. (example: if your permalink structure is /blog/, then your links will be: false->/news/, true->/blog/news/). Defaults to true

```
function uslugi_init() {
$args = array(
  'label' => 'Услуги',
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'page',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'rewrite' => array('with_front' => false, 'slug' => 'uslugi-i-czenyi'),
    'query_var' => true,
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-video-alt',
    'supports' => array(
        'title',
        'editor',
        'excerpt',
        'trackbacks',
        'custom-fields',
        'comments',
        'revisions',
        'thumbnail',
        'author',
        'page-attributes',)
    );
register_post_type( 'uslugi', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'uslugi_init' );
```

Comment: haha, i was faster on 20 seconds=) Thank you Nefro!

Comment: good job :) Aleksandr

Answer (score 1):

So i found a solution.

'with_front' => bool Should the permalink structure be prepended with the front base. (example: if your permalink structure is /blog/, then your links will be: false->/news/, true->/blog/news/). Defaults to true

```
  'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'uslugi-i-czenyi','with_front' => false),
```

Hope helps somebody